# Having exact copy of other excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if there is an easy way of creating a exact copy of an external excel sheet that is on SharePoint. Of course the sheet should be updated whenever the sheet on SharePoint is.

Comment: I've not used SharePoint, but can you not just right click the tab, copy to new workbook?

Answer (score 0):

Ololog,

It sounds like what you're describing is a shortcut to the underlying file. Is this the case, or are you looking to do something else?